# Disable annoying red text highlight in visual studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-editor

Does anyone know how to disable this red text highlight when selecting text in quotes using visual studio?

[image]

I don't know what to try.

Comment: go to options-fonts and colors. It is there

Comment: The settings for such colors are in tools->options->fonts and color. You can reset the settings and it should return to the original state. Please let me know if you are using some extra extension or software which may be due to its effect.

Comment: I'm not using any extensions. Resetting the fonts/color to default does nothing. This red highlight, which isn't the end of the world, only happens with certain strings, mainly css selectors.

Comment: Try to modify tools->options->fonts and colors->[css selector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QvK5.png)(etc). Try these css, if it still doesn’t work, please write to the question Add a sample of your code so I can modify it.

Comment: That's the new Intelisense stuff. Very handy, but sometimes wrong. It will suggest you similar changes as what you've just done in other places. You can disable it under "Options->IntelliCode", but that may disable a bunch of other handy helpers, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to tools->options->intellicode and turn off suggestions.